# WSO2 BAM Hive script error: Database may be already in use

Tags: hive, wso2, h2, wso2-bam

I am trying to execute a simple Hive script from WSO2 BAM and I recieve the following error:

> TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-06-10 17:55:24,752] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBManager} -  Failed to get connection {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBManager}
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode; SQL statement:
>   null/1468667eba66dbdf45540920bcb8b07d6d24451f741 [90020-140]
>   '

Hive script:

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ProjectServicesTable;
>   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ProjectServicesPerDateTable;
>
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProjectServicesTable 
>       (rowID STRING, metaHost STRING, exeTimestamp BIGINT, nickName STRING,
>        description STRING, version STRING) STORED BY 
>       'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler' 
>       WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
>       "wso2.carbon.datasource.name" = "WSO2BAM_CASSANDRA_DATASOURCE",
>       "cassandra.ks.name" = "EVENT_KS" , 
>       "cassandra.cf.name" = "stream1" , 
>       "cassandra.columns.mapping" = 
>       ":key, meta_host, Timestamp, Nick_Name, Description, Version" );
>
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProjectServicesPerDateTable(exeDate STRING, totalServices INT) STORED BY 
>       'org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.JDBCStorageHandler' 
>       TBLPROPERTIES ( 
>       'wso2.carbon.datasource.name'='WSO2_CARBON_DB',
>       'hive.jdbc.update.on.duplicate' = 'true' , 
>       'hive.jdbc.primary.key.fields' = 'exeDate' , 
>       'hive.jdbc.table.create.query' = 
>       'CREATE TABLE PROJECT_SERVICES_DATE_SUMMARY (exeDate VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, totalServices INT)' );
>
> insert overwrite table ProjectServicesPerDateTable 
>       select substring(from_unixtime(cast(exeTimestamp/1000 as BIGINT), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),0,10) as exeDate, count(rowID) as totalServices from ProjectServicesTable
>           group by substring(from_unixtime(cast(exeTimestamp/1000 as BIGINT), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),0,10);

The table PROJECT_SERVICES_DATE_SUMMARY was successfully created.

What is interesting (for me), is that the same script is normally running on another computer, where BAM is configured in the same way. The only difference is the OS - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (script fails) and Windows 7 Professional (script runs well).

Comment: Did you used any other client to query h2 database? Normally in h2, you can't have a concurrent connection unless you specify in the connection url.

Comment: According to the error code, you are using an old version of H2 (version 1.2.140). You should consider upgrading. But most likely, this will not solve the problem. You would need to ensure the database is only opened in one process (as the error message says), or use the server mode, or the automatic mixed mode (see the docs).